# Es posible usar distintas versiones de Java?

Tags: java, javac

Como dice mi pregunta, tengo las ultimas versiones de java 6, 7 y 8 en mi computadora instalados, cada uno con su respectivo jdk, tengo entendido que en el path de windows se agrega la direccion del compilador del java que se usa, pero como puedo hacer para usar los tres javas que tengo? es decir si tengo un programa hecho y quiero compilarlo con java 7 especificamente... actualmente tengo el path de windows con el directorio de java 8, pero es posible elegir entre un compilado y otro? gracias de antemano

Actualizado: perdón voy a agregar poco más de detalles alguno que lo pide, yo estoy usando actualmente Eclipse para desarrollar en Java, pero pensé que eso no tenía mucho que ver con el tema de Path de windows que mencionaba por eso no lo incluí en la información

Comment: Puedes compilar con diferente version de Java pero agrega como lo estas tratando de realizar. Recuerda agregar detalles, estas usando Javac ? Revisar [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para compilar con diferente versiòn usa las opciones

```
-source <release>
-target <release>
```

`-source`: indica la versión que requiere el código fuente para compilar (compatibilidad).

`-target`: Genera archivos de clase que se dirigen a una versión especificada de la VM. Los archivos de clase se ejecutarán en el destino especificado y en versiones posteriores, pero no en versiones anteriores de la VM. Los objetivos válidos son 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 (también 5), 1.6 (también 6) y 1.7 (también 7).
El valor predeterminado para -target depende del valor de -source:

Ejemplo:

```
javac -source 1.6 -target 1.7 Clase.java
```

---

Si deseas cambiar la configuración desde tu IDE estos son ejemplos,

**Netbeans**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Eclipse**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, una información muy útil, esto mismo que me muestras ocurre automáticamente al compilar con un IDE como por ejemplo Eclipse? Por qué al momento de crear un proyecto en Eclipse se puede elegir la versión de Java en la que se quiere programar pero siempre sale una advertencia cuando se elije una versión en la cual no está actualmente en el Path de windows, por ejemplo yo tengo en el Path Java 8, y cuando elijo Java 7 en Eclipse me sale una advertencia y me generaba algunas dudas al respecto de que si se tenía que cambiar el Path manualmente para trabajar con una versión específica

Comment: Claro que si @Gustavo , en la configuración del proyecto se puede realizar, agrego ejemplos para Netbeans y Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Yo trabajo en netbeans y lo que puedes hacer para cambiar la version de Java que se tiene es ir a la ruta donde tienes instalado tu netbeans, una vez ahi deberas buscar la carpeta etc y dentro de esta estara el archivo "netbeans.conf"

En el busca una linea de codigo como esta ***netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3"***

En esta deberas sustituirla por la ruta del jdk que deseas utilizar guardas y listo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra opcion que igual es en netbeans y quiza te sea mas funcional es en la barra de herramientas entras en la opcion tools

Buscas Java Platform

Ahí das en add platform seleccionas la carpeta en donde tengas la version de JDK que deseas utilizar y te quedara algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego deberas ir a las propiedades de tu proyecto dando en clic derecho encima de el nombre del proyecto en la ventana projects de netbeans y luego dando click en properties

En la seccion de sources buscas Source/Binary Format y seleccionas la version de java que deseas tenga tu proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues de esto das click en Ok y listo

Ahora cada vez que quieras cambiar la version de java en tu proyecto solo tendras que entrar en la seccion de **propiedades -> sources** y solo seleccionas la version de java que deseas.

Espero te te sirva bro... Suerte

Comment: ¿Cómo se haría se no se tuviera NetBeans y se usa otro IDE como IntelliJ o si se usas `javac` y `java` desde la CLI del sistema operativo?

Comment: Intellij no lo he usado mucho pero quiza esto te puede servir bro https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/5179825

Comment: Yo uso Eclipse , al momento de crear un nuevo proyecto se indica con que versión de Java se desea trabajar, pero no estoy seguro si esto asegura que al momento de la compilación se compile con esa versión especificada o si o si hay que cambiar nuevamente el Path en Windows antes de compilar , tu sabes que ocurre exactamente?